# AngularJS remove last character if it's a space (directly in HTML)

Tags: angularjs, angular-filters

AngularJS does some magic straight inside HTML, I could say.

I am trying to achieve "stripped description" directly in HTML. So far I managed to limit the displayed characters and added triple dots.

```
<div ng-init="string = 'My string is cool'">
    {{ string | limitTo: 10 }}<span ng-show="string.length > 10">...</span>
</div>
```

But if the string (after limitation) ends with a space, I end up having "end ..." instead of "end...". Is there a way of removing that last space directly in HTML?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just [`trim`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) the limited string:

```
<div ng-init="string = 'My string is cool'">
    {{( string | limitTo: 10 ).trim()}}<span ng-show="string.length > 10">...</span>
</div>
```